# inline iPython call to system

Tags: ipython

I really like to [use system shell commands](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#system-shell-commands) in iPython. But I was wondering if it is possible to loop over the returned values from a call to e.g. `!ls`. This works:

```
files = !ls ./*_subcell_cooc.txt
for f in files:
    print f
```

But this does not:

```
for f in ( !ls ./*_subcell_cooc.txt):
    print f
```

Error is:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-df2bc72907d7>", line 5
   for f in ( !ls $ROOT/*_subcell_cooc.txt):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Any reason for not using the `glob` module for doing this sort of fs querying?

Comment: Not many. Just that I already know and like shell commands. Also, in the rest of that script, I use other commands like `wc`. I will definitively look into `glob`

Comment: I'll admit I was in your position around a year or two ago when I went through the same migration. Honestly I barely touch `bash` these last couple of months doing almost all my scripting in Python (and some node).

Comment: Fair enough, en-route for the grand migration then!

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, the syntax `var = !something` is special cased in IPython. It is **not** valid python syntax, and we will **not** extend for loops and so on to work with it.

You can do assignment as you show in your first example, but using glob,os and other real python module to do that will be more robust, not much harder, and also work outside of IPython...

For the anecdote Guido was really not happy with IPython half-shell syntax when he saw it last time at SciPy2013.

(Also it uppercase I in IPython please.)